# Using php to create a zip file

Tags: php, file, zip, directory

Using the Create ZIP File PHP class I have the following line of code

```
$createZip->get_files_from_folder('blog/wp-content/themes/', 'themes/');
```

Am I right in thinking that this code gets the files and sub directories from 'blog/wp-content/themes/' creates a new folder entitled 'themes', and then puts these files and sub directories into this themes folder.

Comment: I'd suggest just trying it.  You'll probably get the answer faster than here anyway...

Comment: Do you realize that you spent more time typing a Yes/No question than it would actually have taken time to simply try it out?

Comment: maybe more code neede (what is $createZip) ---

Comment: This is not even the zip extension that comes with PHP. It doesn't have such method.

Comment: Maybe include a link to the zip class you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which class/library you are using but here is the one that allows you to zip all files present in specified directory:

[Create Zip File class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2322-PHP-Create-ZIP-file-archives-and-serve-for-download.html)

**Usage:**

```
$fileToZip="License.txt";
$fileToZip1="CreateZipFileMac.inc.php";
$fileToZip2="CreateZipFile.inc.php";

$directoryToZip="./"; // This will zip all the file(s) in this present working directory

$outputDir="/"; //Replace "/" with the name of the desired output directory.
$zipName="test.zip";

include_once("CreateZipFile.inc.php");
$createZipFile=new CreateZipFile;


//Code toZip a directory and all its files/subdirectories
$createZipFile->zipDirectory($directoryToZip,$outputDir);

$rand=md5(microtime().rand(0,999999));
$zipName=$rand."_".$zipName;
$fd=fopen($zipName, "wb");
$out=fwrite($fd,$createZipFile->getZippedfile());
fclose($fd);
$createZipFile->forceDownload($zipName);
@unlink($zipName);
```

Just specify the correct path to variable `$directoryToZip` and all files in it will be zipped.